# Member initializer list in definition or declaration?

Tags: c++, constructor, initializer

Should I declare the member initializer list for a class in the constructor declaration:

```
class A
{
public:
    A(int data) : theData(data);
};
```

or in the constructor definition:

```
A::A(int data) : theData(data)
{
    // code...
};
```

or does it not matter? If you do it a certain way, why?

Comment: You swapped definition <-> declaration. The former is a declaration, the latter is a definition.

Comment: -1 because this is trivial to (a) look up in your book, and (b) try out for yourself in two minutes flat. We expect some level of prior research here at Stack Overflow, which you should know after almost two years.

Comment: "Initialiser list" usually means other things (things that have `{}` around them). Say "member initialiser [list]" or "ctor-initialiser".

Comment: @LightnessRacesInOrbit Just picking up C++, thank you very much. I was just wondering if there was even a way to do it in the declaration.

Comment: @leemes: "member initiali[z]er" is not a "wrong term" - it's the terminology used in the standard. By contrast, grepping it for your "initialization list" (even with "member" omitted) yields zero results.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Hmm,fair enough, my mistake. I'm used to the term "Constructor initialization lists" and short "init-list". And "initializer-list" as the term for literal arrays (`{1,2,3}`). I think it's a bit confusing.

Comment: @leemes: Yes, we should avoid "initializer list". The prefix "member" disambiguates it. I do prefer "ctor-initializer" but it's not as accessible. Admittedly I should probably drop the trailing "list" to make it just "member initializer".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can only have member initializer lists in definitions of your constructors. It is a part of the definition.

Comment: you can also make it inline in the class, just add {} after the list in function .